# Power Bi Rest Api request bearer token works in Postman but not while using ajax?

Tags: ajax, rest, powerbi, postman, powerbi-embedded

so I've been trying to get bearer token to use refresh dataset from my website as an admin tool for faster access on cloud datasets and tables, from official documentation  [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7p9M.png)  it works when trying it from the documentation, but I need bearer token to make it work outside this page, so I found the endpoint on the powerbi forum to do it, I followed the steps from [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/capaw.png) and it works on Postman as intended, but on Ajax it gives me a lot of errors, CORS policy error and code 400(Bad Request), Can you please help me here? What am I missing or doing wrong? how to fix it?

[Screenshot of Postman working endpoint(data changed for security issues)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7p9M.png)

[screenshot ajax Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/capaw.png)

[screenshot ajax Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfTOG.png)

**Here is my ajax code:**

```
  let reqBody = {
            grant_type: "password",
            resource: "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
            username: "username",
            password: "password",
            client_id: "clientid",
            client_secret: "",
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token`,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*"
       },
            data: JSON.stringify(reqBody),
            contentType: "application/json",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("response: ", response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("error: ",error);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When we authorize without setting up CORS for redirect URI, we will face this error. To resolve this error, we need to update the redirect URI for our app to use the spa type.

Refer [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redirect-uris-for-single-page-apps-spas) documentation for more details.